# How to set manipulate Content property while binding?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

Suppose we have the following template.

```
<DataTemplate>
  <CheckBox Content="{Binding FirstName}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

The parent control is bound to a static property of type *Blipp* defines as follows.

```
class Blipp
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public String FirstName { get; set; }
  public String LastName { get; set; }
}
```

What if I'd like the check box to display the full name? Well, I could define a new property and bound to it like so.

```
public String FullName { get { return FirstName + LastName; } }

<CheckBox Content="{Binding FirstName}" />
```

But that's only hiding the actual question. What if I wish to **freely** manipulate the contents of *Content*? One day, maybe I wish the text to be something else. Is that really necessary to keep adding extra properties like so?

```
public String Text1 { get { return FirstName + Id; } }
public String Text2 { get { return LastName + Id; } }
public String Text3 { get { return Id + ") " + FullName; } }
...
```

I'd like, instead, to be able to customize the *Content* property. I tried doing the following but the compiler didn't let me.

```
<DataTemplate>
  <CheckBox Content="{Binding FirstName} + {Binding Id}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a multivalueconverter

[multivalueconverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter(v=vs.110).aspx)

I know link only answer are discouraged but the link has an example of the exact question and a link to msdn is not going to do dead

Comment: So the short (lazy man) answer is no? I had that impression. +1 for spot-on example.